# How can I access C# class attributes inside a Razor engine view file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, attributes

How can I access C# class attributes inside a Razor engine view file?

C# class:

```
[Name="Test"]
public class OrderProgressPage
{
    bool isComplete();
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model ViewModels.OrderProgressPage
<ul>
    <li>@GETAttribute(Name,Model)</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One clean way to do that would be by using a local function in the Razor file

```
@functions
{
    private Test GetTestAttribute(object obj)
    {
        // TODO: This returns null if TestAttribute was not on the class
        TestAttribute myAttribute =
            Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(obj, typeof (TestAttribute)) as TestAttribute;
    }
}

<li>@GetTestAttribute(myClassInstance)</li>
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx

If you need to pass in an attribute name to check, you can use

```
Type.GetType(string typeName)
```

Depending on what you are doing, you could also change GetTestAttribute to a generic function with a signature like

```
private T GetAttribute<T>(object obj)
```